# How can i store the return value from the timestampdiff function

Tags: mysql, timestampdiff

I am using the below query to find the time difference in  minutes.

```
SELECT timestampdiff(minute,created_at,now()) 
AS TIMEDIFF
```

Below is the TIMEDIFF in minutes using the above query

| id | TIMEDIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 193996 | 175 |
| 193997 | 46 |

But when I try to save the output "TIMEDIFF" into a temporary table as Datatype Integer/datetime/time it saves as a different value.
Below is the value retrieved from temporary table saved as integer

| id | TIMEDIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 193996 | 913 |
| 193997 | 913 |

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Please remove the images and post it as text, add expected result as well

Comment: Please add the declare statement for timediff and temporary table definition.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7d367178bb68732f67bd5a822fcd388a

Comment: @P.Salmon :  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TIME_DETAILS(
 ATTEMPT_ID INT,
TIMEDIFF INT);

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue do you have an example where this is happening.